# One word for items used as replacement in an informal way

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be word used for items used as replacement *(like when someone returned a product in a grocery store)*?

An example would be,

**For returned items:**

```
Total Items Returned: 777
```

**For those used  as replacement:**

```
Total Items ______: 12
```

I was thinking of using `replaced`, but that would mean **"Items that are replaced"**, rather that **"Items used as replacement"**

The format is like that because it will be used in a program

Comment: Are you substituting item for item, or total value? Items *exchanged* or *issued (as replacements)* might work.

Comment: @Davo It's item for an item

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it seems like [**substituted**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/substitute) could be a good fit for the purpose.

From ODE:

> *Substitute*: 
>   
>   1. A person or thing acting or serving in place of another.

Comment: I think *"Total Items Substitued"* is still ambiguous, in the same way the OP recognises that *"Total Items Replaced"* is. I would use *"Total Substitute Items" or *Total Replacement Items"* instead.